# pointwise convergence of series?

Tags: convergence-divergence

We have just been introduced to infinite series of functions, and immediately started working on uniform convergence and Weierstrass' M-test, and how the sum of the series behaves in terms of integration, differentiation, etc.

But what about 'pointwise' convergence of a series of functions, like we had for sequences? What's the definition for that? Do I simply pick and $x$, and show that the series I get (which is one of numbers $a_n$) is convergent, or is there more to it?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is the product topology. The trouble with this thing is that it is rarely metrizable and it's pretty nasty.